# Why is the `operation on 'i' may be undefined`and how to fix this warning?

Tags: c++

The `operation on 'i' may be undefined` appears at the second `i++` in the line as follows:

```cpp
int i = 4;
const uint16_t rawVoltage = (rxBuffer[i++]<<8) | rxBuffer[i++];
```

I believe it is related to the order of operations, but I guess the parenthesis has priority over the last increment.

Btw, the code works fine, as expected, just want to address the warning.

Comment: Don't  do `i++` twice in the same statement like that, it's just asking for trouble, that's what the compiler is trying to tell you.

Comment: It is not fully defined when the `++`'s happens. Here do not even do it once. Did you intend `[i] ... [i+1] ...; i += 2;`?

Comment: Yep, rx is the reception buffer, from where I want to consume bytes one after the other. The very line just build a 16-bit value from a big endian layout out of the rx stream. Btw, the code works fine, as expected.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parentheses affect parsing but not order of evaluation. You have two operations in your expression that modify `i`: `i++` on the left-hand side and `i++` on the right-hand side.

In general the order of evaluation is not specified in C++. For some operators certain sequencing rules apply, but in particular `|` does not enforce any sequencing of the two operands. Therefore there is no sequencing rule enforcing any order between the left- and right-hand `i++`.

The standard says that if the value computation or a side effect is unsequenced with another side effect on the same scalar object, then the behavior is undefined. That is the case here on `i`.

The solution is to split the statement into two:

```
uint16_t rawVoltage = (rxBuffer[i++]<<8);
rawVoltage |= rxBuffer[i++];
```

---

> Btw, the code works fine, as expected, just want to address the warning.

That's by pure luck. The program has undefined behavior and compilers do make use of that for optimization. Even if it was not undefined behavior the order between the two operands would be unspecified and compilers will also reorder evaluation in such cases if that gives an optimization advantage or they may by default use different orders.

Comment: can't have `const uint16_t rawVoltage` and two statements

Comment: @Caleth Right, corrected.

Comment: Great answer. While it's a recurring question I can't find a better answer for C++ for novices.